# what is the way of saving image path to mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I am developing REST API using nodeJS, express, mongoose etc with mongodb. I am uploading file and saving it to a folder using multer. Now I want to save the path of the file to a mongodb document.

However, I am saving data to mongodb using mongoose schema. First I created the model. When a post request is made, I read it using bodyParser (req.body) and save this object by creating new instance or more shortcut.

```js
Product.create(req.body).then(function(product){
  res.send(product);
}).catch(next);
```

But when I am using multer to upload a file and want to save the path to the model I cant do it using create() function. So what is the way ??

Comment: Please show exactly the code that failed. And trusting the client to send a valid request and directly put that into the db sounds a bit too good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can upload the image into some destination you want, this is for the [reference](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@morningtundra/storing-and-retreiving-images-in-mongodb-with-nodejs) for more details information including how to access stored images in Mongodb and you can see the documentation [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) about multer.

```
express = require('express')
   , router = express.Router()
   , MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
   , ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId
   , fs = require('fs-extra')
   // Your mongodb or mLabs connection string
   , url = 'mongodb://username:password@yourinstanced.mlab.com:29459/yourdb'
   , multer = require('multer')
   , util = require('util')
   , upload = multer({limits: {fileSize: 2000000 },dest:'/uploads/'})

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) { 
   // req.file is the `avatar` file
   // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
        if (req.file == null) {
       // If Submit was accidentally clicked with no file selected...
    )} else { 
       MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
       // this landing will give you any option of file information that you can collect
        console.log('landing here', req.file)
       // read the img file from tmp in-memory location
       var newImg = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
       // encode the file as a base64 string.
       var encImg = newImg.toString('base64');
       // define your new document
       var newItem = {
          contentType: req.file.mimetype,
          size: req.file.size,
          name: req.file.originalname,
          path: req.file.path
       };
    db.collection('yourcollectionname')
       .insert(newItem, function(err, result){
       if (err) { console.log(err); };
          var newoid = new ObjectId(result.ops[0]._id);
          fs.remove(req.file.path, function(err) {
             if (err) { console.log(err) };
             res.send(newItem);
             });
          });
       });
    }});
```

Comment: why you encode the file as base64 but not use `encImg` variable for saving to mongoDB?

Answer (score 2):

In the MongoDB we can store single or multiple images. For storing multiple images I am using productPictures array.

**1: First, create the Product model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    productPictures: [{ img: { type: String } }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

**2: Create the product controller**

```
const Product = require('../models/product');

exports.createProduct = (req, res) => {
  const { name} = req.body;

  let productPictures = [];

  if (req.files.length > 0) {
    productPictures = req.files.map((file) => {
      return { img: file.filename };
    });
  }

  const product = new Product({
    name,
    productPictures,
  });

  product.save((error, product) => {
    if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
    if (product) {
      res.status(201).json({ product });
    }
  });
};
```

**3: Create products route file**

- I am using **nanoid** to generate a unique name for images
- Create uploads folder inside src folder

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');
const { createProduct } = require('../controllers/product');
const router = express.Router();


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), 'uploads'));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, nanoid() + '-' + file.originalname);
  },
});


const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post(
  '/products/create',
  upload.array('productPicture'), // for storing single image : upload.single('productPicture')
  createProduct
);

module.exports = router;
```

**4: Create server.js file**

```
const env = require('dotenv');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

// routes
const productRoutes = require('./routes/product');

env.config();

mongoose
  .connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database connected');
  });

// Body parser (You can you **body-parser**)
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api', productRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

**5: Finally you can create product using postman**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If using multer you will get uploaded files path in `req.file.path` and you just need to save that in your database.

Comment: can you share an example ?